# Variable in text not replaced and still with braces

Tags: ansible, jinja2

There is a json file (this content is transferring as base64 to playbook):

```
$ cat json
{
  "name": "some_value",
  "envs": "ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT={{additional_variable}}"
}
```

Convert to b64 format:

```
$ cat json | base64 | tr -d "\n"
ewogICJuYW1lIjogInNvbWVfdmFsdWUiLAogICJlbnZzIjogIkVOVl9URVNUPXRydWUgRU5WX1RFWFQ9e3thZGRpdGlvbmFsX3ZhcmlhYmxlfX0iCn0K
```

Extra vars for playbook (additional_variable and json_props):

```
-e additional_variable=additionaltext -e json_props=ewogICJuYW1lIjogInNvbWVfdmFsdWUiLAogICJlbnZzIjogIkVOVl9URVNUPXRydWUgRU5WX1RFWFQ9e3thZGRpdGlvbmFsX3ZhcmlhYmxlfX0iCn0K
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    props: "{{ json_props | b64decode | from_json }}"
    prop:
      envs: "{{ props.envs }}"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ additional_variable }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ prop.envs }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "additionaltext"
}

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT={{additional_variable}}"
}
```

How to set variable additional_variable from extra vars to the prop.envs string?

Any ideas?

I expect that output will be "ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT=additionaltext"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the variable *props* have already been 'templated' in the expression

```yaml
  props: "{{ json_props|b64decode|from_json }}"
```

You've already found out that given the extra variables

```yaml
shell> cat evars.yml
additional_variable: additionaltext
json_props: ewogICJuYW1lIjogInNvbWVfdmFsdWUiLAogICJlbnZzIjogIkVOVl9URVNUPXRydWUgRU5WX1RFWFQ9e3thZGRpdGlvbmFsX3ZhcmlhYmxlfX0iCn0K
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    props: "{{ json_props|b64decode|from_json }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: props
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e @evars.yml pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  props:
    envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT={{additional_variable}}
    name: some_value
```

The variable *additional_variable* was not substituted in the attribute *envs* and explicit expansion of the attribute doesn't help either. Ansible doesn't provide a tool to 'template' a value of a variable in *vars*. But, you can create a custom filter on your own

```py
shell> cat plugins/filter/template.py
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader


def template(my_string, my_vars):
    rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(my_string)
    return(rtemplate.render(my_vars))


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'template': template,
        }
```

Configure the path to the filter plugins [DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-filter-plugin-path). For example,

```ini
shell> grep filter ansible.cfg 
filter_plugins = $PWD/plugins/filter
```

and use the filter *template*. As a second argument of the filter you have to provide a dictionary with the variables the template needs for the substitutions

```yaml
  prop:
    envs: "{{ props.envs|template(vars) }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  prop:
    envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT=additionaltext
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    props: "{{ json_props|b64decode|from_json }}"
    prop:
      envs: "{{ props.envs|template(vars) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: props
    - debug:
        var: additional_variable
    - debug:
        var: prop

    - set_fact:
        envs: "{{ props.envs|template(my_vars) }}"
      vars:
        my_vars:
          additional_variable: "{{ additional_variable }}"
    - debug:
        var: envs
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e @evars.yml pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  props:
    envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT={{additional_variable}}
    name: some_value

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  additional_variable: additionaltext

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  prop:
    envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT=additionaltext

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT=additionaltext

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

- A simpler option is passing the filename instead of the encoded content. For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.json 
{
  "name": "some_value",
  "envs": "ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT={{ additional_variable }}"
}
```

include the variables from the file into a dictionary by *include_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ file_json_props }}"
        name: props
    - debug:
        var: props
```

This way the expressions are 'templated' (expanded) automatically

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e additional_variable=additionaltext -e file_json_props=/tmp/test.json pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  additional_variable: additionaltext

TASK [include_vars] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  props:
    envs: ENV_TEST=true ENV_TEXT=additionaltext
    name: some_value

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I added an example of how to provide a filename in the extra variable instead of the encoded content of the file. I'm curious about the use case. Why do you have to put the content of the file into the extra variable? Why are you not able to provide a filename in the extra variables? This would justify the implementation of the filter *template*.

Comment: This is the approach of the project, I don't want to change it because we have a lot of dependencies on it (mb in the future). Every run extra vars were added dynamically.
Thanks a lot, it really help me.